# Oracle external connection

Tags: sql, oracle, amazon-ec2, oracle11g

I am not an expert in oracle, and I have to accomplish something bigger than my knowledge.

I have setup a Windows Server 2008R2 with an oracle server 11g (11.2) and a small database (MYDB) in amazon EC2.

Now I want to connect from my computer to this database (I use PL/SQL developer) but I don't mind using other tools.

I've setup the tnsnames with :

```
MYDB =
   (DESCRIPTION =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 12.345.678.910)(PORT = 1521))
     (CONNECT_DATA =
       (SERVICE_NAME = MYDB)
     )
   )
```

where 12.345.678.910 is the public ip for my Win server.

When I am trying to connect I have no luck.

Of course I suspect that I need some more steps (If I am wrong please correct me):
 1. I need to give somewhere the credentials for the Win server before trying to connect to database.
 2. I have to allow my database to accept external connections.

Could you please give me some directions, solutions, anything that will help me?

Comment: Do you know your `SID`?

Comment: What are you using to connect to the database (SQL Developer?) and what error code are you getting?

Comment: Yes it is the same as MYDB

Comment: @KevinKirkpatrick I am using Pl/SQL developer and I get ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occured

Comment: Can you ping that IP Address?

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 No I can't

Comment: Propably is http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1145#18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My sequence of steps for troubleshooting

1. Is the database resolvable? `C:\>tnsping MYDB` (Confirms: the database listener is running on serverside)
2. Is there a firewall issue? `C:\>telnet hostname 1521` (Probably your case)
3. Can I login? `C:\>sqlplus system/pass@MYDB` or `C:\>sqlplus system/pass@hostname:1521/MYDB` (Confirms: The database is available)
4. Finally, chances of having a successful login with your favorite dev-tool has increased by 100%

Comment: Thanks. I'll try later and let you know. Thanks for your time

Comment: Brand : 2 is failing :could not open connection to the host, on port 1521: Connect failed

Comment: thanks for your time. I found my solution there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22610792/ora-12170-tns-listener-in-oracle-11g/22611882?noredirect=1#22611882