# ORA-12170 TNS listener in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, amazon-ec2, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper, ora-12170

I have setup a Windows Server 2008R2 with an oracle server 11g (11.2) and a small database (MYDB) in amazon EC2.

Now I want to connect from my computer to this database (I use PL/SQL developer but I don't mind using other tools)

In server side I have: (where ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com is the public DNS for my Win server.)
tnsnames.ora:

```
 MYDB =
   (DESCRIPTION =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com)(PORT = 1521))
     (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = MYDB)
     )
   )
```

listener.ora:

```
 # listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
 # Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

 LISTENER =
     (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
      (DESCRIPTION =
       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com)(PORT = 1521))
       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      )
    )

   ADR_BASE_LISTENER = C:\app\Administrator
```

At my pc at tnsnames.ora i have:

```
 MYDB=
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
     (SERVICE_NAME = MYDB)
    )
  )
```

With these settings, I am able to connect locally at my server, but not through my computer.
I have setup up Security Groups at my EC2:

Inbound rules

```
Type                Protocol              Port Range     Source
RDP                 TCP                   3389           Anywhere 0.0.0.0/0
SSH                 TCP                   22             Anywhere 0.0.0.0/0
Custom ICMP Rule    Echo Reply            N/A            Anywhere 0.0.0.0/0
```

When I am trying to connect from my computer I get

> ORA-12170:TNS:Connect timeout occurred.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong, or a troubleshooting plan?

Comment: Surely you need an inbound rule for port 1521? Or are you planning to tunnel it over SSH, in which case your PC `tnsnames.ora` entry needs to reflect that? Why is the question title referring to ORA-12514 but the body ORA-12170?

Comment: @Alex Poole. Could you please explain a bit more? I just want to connect through PL/SQL developer.

Comment: @AlexPoole :Sorry, wrong copy paste. I've changed the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [security groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html) only allow RDP and SSH access, on ports 3389 and 22 (plus ICMP ping). When you attempt to connect to the database you're using port 1521, as your `tnsnames.ora` dictates:

```
(HOST = ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com)(PORT = 1521))
```

So you need to [add an inbound firewall rule](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#adding-security-group-rule) to allow traffic on TCP port 1521 through to your EC2 instance, in addition to the existing ones for 3389 and 22. I have no idea if SQL*Net will be listed in the 'type' drop down, so you might need to select 'All TCP'.

You might also want to make it more restrictive though - limiting the 'source' to your PC's IP address perhaps if this is private, or your company's outgoing Ip if not; if you have a static public IP from your ISP.

Comment: Ok but which type of rule I should add?

Comment: I don't know what's in the 'Type' drop-down. It would be nice if it had `SQL*Net', or 'Oracle Net' - something pre-populated with TCP/1521. The 'Any TCP' option looks unrestricted, which isn't ideal; really you want to be able to choose a single port. Actually... [see step 4 in this walk-through](http://www.pythian.com/blog/how-to-get-started-with-amazon-ec2-oracle-11g-xe-example/).

Comment: Thanks. You are my GOD.
I have spent more than 3 days. You are genious.

Comment: Just for the record, the Inbound rule was - Type:Custom TCP rule, Protocol: TCP  Port Range:1521